# How to use ORDER BY FIELD with subquery in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, subquery

Suppose there are two tables. First table, 'user_actions', has two fields: 'user_id' and 'action'. Second table, 'users', also has two fields: 'id' and 'name'. I want to sort the first table so that actions commited by users Aaron or Bruce go first and actions commited by Yuriy and Zorro go last. How would I do that?

I tried this:

```
select * from `user_actions` order by field(`user_id`,(select distinct `id` from `users` order by `name`))
```

Doesn’t work.

Comment: there is any other syntax which allow use subqueries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why the subquery and not a join?

Something like this:

```
select ua.*
from user_actions ua inner join users u on ua.user_id = u.id
order by u.name
```

Comment: Doesn’t it take all pairs of rows of those two tables? If so, I believe that’s an inefficient solution.

Comment: If the indexes are created properly it shouldn't. Examine the execution plan for that query and check it yourself.

Answer (score 3):

```
select ua.user_id, ua.action, u.name from user_actions ua
inner join users u on u.user_id = ua.user_id
order by u.name
```

Comment: Doesn’t it take all pairs of rows of those two tables? If so, I believe that’s an inefficient solution.

Comment: This query will take all rows from the `user_actions` table, "lookup" the name of the user based on the matching `user_id` in the `users` table, and order by the `name` field.  I think this would be the most common solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
select user_id,action from user_actions join users 
  on user_actions.user_id = users.id 
  order by name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
SELECT u1.user_id, u1.action, u2.name FROM user_actions u1, users u2
WHERE u1.user_id=u2.id 
ORDER BY u2.name
```

Comment: Although right, that way you are doing a join through the where clause and that's not the proper way to do it.

Answer (score -1):

i suppose this query would suffice

```
SELECT * FROM user_actions ORDER BY name
```

Order by keyword by default sorts in ascending, so wont need ASC after the 'name' field. If you want the opposite way just add DESC after 'name'

Comment: user_actions table doesn't have a name column according to the question.